# Server to client and client to server communication for security

Tags: proxy-server

After analyzing my work situation for quite a while I decided to implement a solution to the sharing problem which we're having at work.

The problem is we have many laptops at work and we need to share internet, files, printer across all. Currently we're sharing internet using WLAN Tether from Windows 7 machine and it works good.

Now what do I plan to do is that. I want to have a Ubuntu server which will share internet, files, printer over all clients there on workplace wirelessly. I also want every client to communicate only to that server keeping every client's sharing off to other clients or servers. I know it's possible but what open source/paid tools I would require?

My another question is about how to proxify the internet flowing through server to clients so to restrict the clients internet usage. I also want to have statistics of internet usage of what website was visited by whom and who downloaded what from where and everything that can help evaluate my employees. Any ideas?

I am much techie but haven't experienced such tools before so I thought the best way to ask is SuperUser.

Comment: I suggest you split this into two questions as they are two very different topics and will need to be answered separately.  Move the proxy question to a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proxy I would suggest checking out http://www.squid-cache.org/